# Multiple conditions

Tags: php

I'm new to php and having some trouble. I wanted to add the same widget to the 3rd and 6th posts of my blog. I currently have

```
<div class="addArea">
                    <?php $i++;
                    if($i==3){get_sidebar(add);} ?>
</div>
```

Add that works fine for the 3rd, but how would I add it to the sixth post as well?

I tried the following but no luck

```
<div class="addArea">
                    <?php $i++;
                    if($i==2){get_sidebar(add);} if($i==3){get_sidebar(add);} ?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `if ($i == 3 || $i == 6)` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Get all the powers of three with if (( $i % 3 ) == 0 )

Comment: Who's downvoting this? The user is new to PHP and to SO. It's a clear question backed up with a code sample. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="addArea">
<?php 
     $i++;
     if ($i == 3 || $i == 6) { get_sidebar(add); } 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you all so much! I tried if ($i == 3 || $i == 6) and (( $i % 3 ) == 0 ) but it weirdly still just added it only to the 3rd post. I'm wondering if it's better to setup a different widget for the sixth post